# How to make the height fixed and still while adding more numbers that it can show to the EditText?

Tags: android, layout, textview, tablerow

I used this code to put in 1 line two EditText's, but when I type more numbers that the field can show, it gets big enough until show all numbers(including hidding other blank EditText's), and with this, change the height of all the next buttons on the code.

The TableRow selected is the same as the one on the code below

[code http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/21/bm0c.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/21/bm0c.png)

Here's the code:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_height="50.0sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="@string/Numero1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_height="50.0sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="@string/Numero2"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: When I put a lot of numbers on the edittext, it get's bigger and hide all the others buttons. I want to fix its size independently of the numbers typed and, with the scrollhorizontally, see what I typed, instead of show all the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this-

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50.0sp"
        android:hint="@string/Numero1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50.0sp"
        android:hint="@string/Numero2"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>
```

add "**android:singleLine**" attribute, this will keep your Edittext limited to one row only.